# Adding white space around plot in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have a figure with a fixed size and want to change the size of the plot inside it, i.e., add white space around it. Most questions online deal with removing white space or subplots, which I don't have.

My plotting code is

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(14,10))
plt.plot(n, y)
plt.savefig('figure.png', bbox_inches='tight', dpi=200)
```

so really nothing special. I already tried `margins` and `tight_layout(pad = X)` but nothing worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can adjust the subplot parameters using `subplots_adjust`

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(14, 10))
plt.plot(n, y)

#Adjust the subplot parameters to add white space
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.1, right=0.9, top=0.9, bottom=0.1)

plt.savefig('figure.png', dpi=200)
```

by adjusting the values for left, right, top, and bottom, you can control the amount of white space added around the plot.

Comment: This seems to shrink the plot, but I don't get any extra white space :/

Comment: ah, okay. Got it. I also have to remove the bbox_inches='tight' :)